# I'm trying to loop my code so that if input is invalid it'll keep looping

Tags: python-3.x

Is there a way to loop this code so that it keep asking for the correct input. I'm new to python and getting this far was a miracle

Kind regards
Harrry

```
   import re

r = re.compile(r'[a -z A -Z]')
print("Welcome to this questionnaire:")
x = input("Your Name:")

while not r.match(x):
    print("Come on,'", x, "' can't be your name")
    x = input("Your Name:")

if 3 <= len(x) <= 10:
    print("Hi,", x, "!")
elif len(x) > 10:
    print("Mmm,Your name is too long!")
elif len(x) < 3:
    print("Sorry, your name is too short!")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
import re

r = re.compile(r"^[A-Za-z]*$")        #Match only alpha
print("Welcome to this questionnaire:")
x = input("Your Name:")

while not r.match(str(x)):
    print("Come on,'", x, "' can't be your name")
    x = input("Your Name:")
```

Or you can use `str.isalpha`

```
print("Welcome to this questionnaire:")
x = input("Your Name:")
while not str(x).isalpha():
    print("Come on,'", x, "' can't be your name")
    x = input("Your Name:")
```

Comment: Thanks Rakesh, the first one has worked tremendously however is it possible to get a description of what you've done as I'd like to know for future reference.

Comment: You are welcome :) I have just corrected the regex to match only string.